# Python Dictionary to csv , but all keys as seperate individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, dataframe

I am Having my dictionary as my_dict

```
print(my_dict)


{'columns': ['Ball_ID', 'Item-Score'],
'data': [['B1', 5],
['B2', 5],
['B3', 5],
['B4', 5],
['B5', 5],
['B6', 5],
['B7', 5],
['B8', 5],
['B9', 5]}
```

I want my csv as

```
B1,B2,B3,B4.....
5  5  5   5....
```

I want to create a CSV as all Keys as Separate individual columns and Values under respective keys.
or I can work with Pandas to create a csv as above requirements.
But , above format is important.Please can anyone answer me

Comment: You need to create a dictionary out of the `data` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need `DataFrame` constructor with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `transpose`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'], columns=d['columns']).set_index('Ball_ID').T
#more general
#df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'], columns=d['columns']).set_index(d['columns'][0]).T
print (df)
Ball_ID     B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9
Item-Score   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5

#for write to file
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `my_dict['data']` to a dictionary, then write that to the CSV file.

```
rowdict = {x[0]: x[1] for x in my_dict['data']}
with open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
    csv = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=rowdict);
    csv.writeheader()
    csv.writerow(rowdict)
```

Comment: `dict` variaable name will shadow the builtin function `dict()`. Also `list(dict)` is recommended over `list(dict.keys())`

Comment: @jamylak Could I just use `fieldnames=rowdict` without creating the list first?